# Emulate connected Bluetooth device as keyboard

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard, avr, pic

I have a simple bluetooth modul that can connect as a serial port. My question is is it possible to emulate this serial as a keyboard on an Android phone?

I am trying to make a simple Bluetooth keyboard with a PIC and this device for my Pho ne.

Answer (score 0):

no :( You need the module with profile "Human Interface Device Profile (HID)" for Android to detect it as a keyboard, but you have a module with "Serial Port Profile (SPP)" profile

Comment: Is there a way to emulate the keyb? I mean, run an app in the back that gets the data and sends "emulated" key s to the Android?